# VueJs child components in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I've trouble using components and child components in Vue.js. I can't get the correct DOM using child components and v-repeats at the custom tags. This is my code: http://laravel.io/bin/rowQx

I can't understand even though I've scratched my head for hours why the repeated role-user tags are placed after the form-group but before the entire table.
The placement of the  tags is before . Why so? Why does it not land in the  components in  as I thought since it's where it's placed. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the reason behind this is that you're not allowed to put <role-user> tags inside a tbody since it executes as invalid table html output.

Anyone who have experience in fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this issue is solvable. Check the code and [manual article](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#is_attribute).

```
<tr is="role-user" v-for="user in usersList"></tr>
```

I'm not sure if `v-for` won't break in here. As a workaround, you can use `template`.

```
<template v-for="user in usersList">
    <tr is="role-user"></tr>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the content Tag in your User-Table view to render the nested child. Place it in the Position where you want to render it like the yield in laravel

Comment: As you can see in this link there's a tag in the users-table http://laravel.io/bin/rowQx#78 :)

Comment: What do you mean with the Content Tag? Could you please try to take my code and give me a hint after you've edited it?

Comment: Sorry at this Moment i am only on Phone. But when i am home i will give you an example

Comment: Try this, it's untested and i hope it is working

http://laravel.io/bin/1y6Kj#79-80

Comment: Thanks. But what should it do? I already have my child component role-user which doesn't appends correctly in that tbody. Why should <content> do so?

Comment: content is the equivalent to yield in laravel. i say vue, please render all components here ;)

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't add a tbody after a table was rendered. I guess that's some kind of HTML issue or rule that exists.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to go away with a div structure. I think it's not possible to add a tbody / table rows when the html is already rendered.